# Configure Camel Thread names with Spring DSL

Tags: spring, apache-camel

How do I configure the thread names created by Camel (version 2.8.1)? I need to have more concise thread names for logging purposes.

The [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html) states that the default is:

```
Camel (#camelId#) thread ##counter# - #name#
```

Which results in names like:

```
Camel (bundle_camel) thread #114 - JmsConsumer[SomeClassNameHere]
```

But I want just:

```
#camelId#-#counter#
```

which would give me something like:

```
bundle_camel-114
```

The documentation says how to change the thread name pattern by calling a manager method, but we only ever interact with Camel via the Spring DSL config files.

Comment: Could you show the DSL configuration part?As indicated in the documentation, you should use the older placeholder style `${camelId}` instead of `#camelId#` since you are using a version pre 2.10.

Comment: That's the whole point, Oliver. I don't have anywhere in the DSL that configures anything to do with Camel thread names. I need to find out where and how the thread names are configured in the DSL for the Camel context.

Comment: Have you tried to define a `ExecutorServiceStrategy` that set the `ThreadNamePattern` and specify it where you use a threadpool? That is why I wanted to see your current configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you would need to define a `<bean>` with the executor service strategy and set its pattern. Though I think we should allow to configure a naming pattern as an attribute on `<camelContext>` which you can do for JMX naming. I will log a ticket to get this enhanced in Camel (though ASF JIRA is currently in maintenance mode)

See some details at http://camel.apache.org/advanced-configuration-of-camelcontext-using-spring.html and http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html

Answer (score 1):

Camel 2.11 makes this easier.

You can use the threadNamePattern attribute in the XML files as shown below:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" threadNamePattern="#camelId#-#counter#">
  <route>
      ...
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Documented [here](http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html).